# simultaneous events on separate divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my jquery code I am hoping to slide my menu up, thus moving the button up that is used to click it. I would like this to happen at the same time however I am yet to find away to do two methods on different divs at the same time.

The current javascript I am using is:

```
$( "#mobile-menu-button" ).click(function() {
if ($("#mobile-menu").css("display") == "block") {

   $('#mobile-menu').slideUp("slow");
 $('#mobile-menu-button').animate({top:"0px" }, 700 );


     var h = $('.navigation').css("height").replace("px", "");


}
else{
  $('#mobile-menu').slideDown("slow");
  var h = $('.navigation').css("height").replace("px", "");
  $('#mobile-menu-button').animate({top:h},300);
 }
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle of my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/FM92V/

Comment: some of your code is outside the code block, didn't realize it at first

Comment: thanks, slipped past me also

Comment: are you trying to make them move at the same rate?  because a slow slide is 600ms and your button moves at 700 and then 300 ms.

Comment: They also seem to have different easings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to move elements in any way (or animate them), the time must be the same. If you replace the milliseconds with the string 'slow', it is working correctly.

```
$( "#mobile-menu-button" ).click(function() {
if ($("#mobile-menu").css("display") == "block") {

   $('#mobile-menu').slideUp("slow");
 $('#mobile-menu-button').animate({top:"0px" }, 'slow');


     var h = $('.navigation').css("height").replace("px", "");


}
else{
  $('#mobile-menu').slideDown("slow");
  var h = $('.navigation').css("height").replace("px", "");
  $('#mobile-menu-button').animate({top:h},'slow');
 }
});
```

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FM92V/2/ . Also, remove the `height:75%` from `#mobile-menu` in CSS

Comment: that works in the JSFiddle, which is annoying because applied in my code. It doesnt work the same

Comment: Do you have a real implication of it anywhere, that I could check and review?

Comment: i've just uploaded it to http://www.whereslouis.com.

to view the button, the window size needs to be smaller than 640px wode

Comment: It does work. As I stated after the large code block, remove `height:75%;` from `#mobile-menu` in CSS! P.S. This will cause an issue for the screen if the size is larger than 640px, but you can add a CSS `@media screen and (max-width: 640px){ #mobile-menu{height:auto} }`

Comment: thanks, why the height made a difference to the overall effect im not sure.